# Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, react-hooks

I'm typescript beginner, i have set types for props as you can see but getting error:
Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
(property) AA.action?: string | undefined

any advice/help ?
my code:

```js
interface AA {
  action?: string;
  actionArgs?: string;
}

const ArticleList: React.FC<AA> = (props) => {
  const data = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => {
    const secondData = {
      sites: state.articles.sites,
      analysers: state.siteArticles.analysers,
    };

    return secondData[props.action];
  });
```

if i remove optional then getting more errors:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ sites: any; analysers: any; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ sites: any; analysers: any; }'.ts(7053)

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: maybe you can try to replace action?: string; to action: 'sites' | 'analysers'

Comment: @DraganS it worked, could you explain reason ?

Comment: `props.action` is a `string`,  a string can be any string. By doing `'sites' | 'analysers'` you have narrowed the type to valid types of your secondData const.  If you want action to optional, you could also use a type guard, `if (props.action) {` or at least allow for a default `return secondData[props.action || 'sites']`.  To make things dry, personally I would also have an interface for your sencondData, and then you could use `actions?: keyof ISecondData`

Comment: Soon you will add more fields next to sites, ... If you define the type for secondData - let's call it MyType, you can use  keyof MyType instead of 'sites' | 'an...' | 'moreFields' and this will "scale" better as you don't need to manually update this list of keys: Mhttps://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html

Comment: @DraganS could you write it as an answer with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
interface AA {
  action: keyof MySecondData;
  actionArgs?: string;
}

interface MySecondData {
  sites: string_I_guess[],
  analysers: Analysers[],
};

const ArticleList: React.FC<AA> = (props) => {
  const data = useSelector((state: RootStateOrAny) => {
    const secondData: MySecondData = {
      sites: state.articles.sites,
      analysers: state.siteArticles.analysers,
    };

    return secondData[props.action];
  });
```